# Can linux abstract sockets using a psk as name be found by another user?

Tags: linux, access-control

If an abstract unix socket is named "\0some random secret", can it be guessed or retrieved somehow from the abstract socket namespace beyond using brute force?

Are there more security related downsides compared to normal unix sockets which is subject to file system access control?

Comment: Is there a certain problem you are trying to solve with this? Maybe that's a question of its own.

Comment: The problem with normal unix sockets is that it is really hard to manage their lifecycle (i.e. removing them). However, they have the advantage over network sockets, that they can be put under access control. The nice thing is that all implementations are mostly interchangable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's not secure. You can enumerate sockets with `ss -xa`, even ones from processes that aren't yours. To test, run this:

```
#include <stddef.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/un.h>

int main(void) {
    struct sockaddr_un addr = {
      .sun_family = AF_UNIX,
      .sun_path = "\0some random secret"
    };
    int sockfd = socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    bind(sockfd, &addr, offsetof(struct sockaddr_un, sun_path) + 19);
    listen(sockfd, 50);
    accept(sockfd, NULL, NULL);
    return 0;
}
```

And then as another user, do `ss -xa` and you'll see an entry like `u_str  LISTEN     0      50     @some random secret 12979431              * 0` in the output.